# Two columns - Unbreakable

Tags: multicolumn

The following M(merly)WE has a failure: it puts material 5 and 6 on two different pages. That is a normal feature of `multicols` and the good one as I sue it.

[image]

How can I avoid this knowing that I can't work with floats (due to pedagogical bad reasons)? Playing with penalities? Using a different approach?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand\fakematerial[1]{
    Material #1 - START

    \vspace{7cm}
    
    Material #1 - END 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \fakematerial{1}
    
    \columnbreak
    
    \fakematerial{2}
\end{multicols}


\begin{multicols}{2}
    \fakematerial{3}
    
    \columnbreak
    
    \fakematerial{4}
\end{multicols}


\begin{multicols}{2}
    \fakematerial{5}
    
    \columnbreak
    
    \fakematerial{6}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't want things to be page breakable you can nest the `multicols` inside a `minipage`.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to entirely stick to side-by-side minipages if you don't want lnebrekeas to occur within a "matrial"?

Comment: @leandriis Good point. I never used `minipage` but here it should do the job. I test it now.

Answer (score 1):

What failure?

You have used a macro 3 times and each insert a rigid space of 7 cm (in total more than  `597 pt`, without count the lines of text and interline spaces), but all the vertical space available for the text is `592 pt`.

You only need to correct the vertical space. Simply reduce the vertical to 1/3 of the text height, minus the space of the lines of text and the line skips:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand\fakematerial[1]{%
    Material #1 - START%
    \par\vspace{\dimexpr.33\textheight-2\baselineskip-2\lineskip}\par%
    Material #1 - END\par} 
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \fakematerial{1}
    \columnbreak
    \fakematerial{2}
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \fakematerial{3}
    \columnbreak
    \fakematerial{4}
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \fakematerial{5}
    \columnbreak
    \fakematerial{6}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

However, this is still unnecessarily complicated and rigid (any layout variation, as a change of \parskip, for instance, will be enough to spoil this solution).

For only two columns, you only need `\vfill` in true twocolumn mode, without `multicol`. This way you can even enter some extra between the tree `\fakematerial` macros of one column (including one more macaro) and LaTeX will take care to distribute the available space (if there are still any) in the column:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 12pt]{article}
\newcommand\fakematerial[1]{Material #1 - START \vfill  Material #1 - END\par} 
\begin{document}
    \fakematerial{1} 
    \fakematerial{3}
    \fakematerial{5} \newpage
    \fakematerial{2}
    \fakematerial{4}
    \fakematerial{6}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: The vertical spacing was for a fake material. ;-)

Comment: Do you mean that `7cm` is not a constant space to be filled at hand but "represent" some already present (variable?) content? Then it was also a fake example :-)  Anyway, the underlying  problem is the same. Fake or true material, if it is a bigger that it  should,  you can boxit to make it unbreakable, but at the cost of  awful vertical gap. Better take care of the height, fit it if possible, otherwise allow generous glues whitin-between materials to disguise the excess of space (or, well, allow some breaks).  BTW, consider use the flexibility of `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do that is to use `minipage` as pointed into the comments of **Skillmon** and **leandriis**.

Here is a hard-coded solution (that is just a starting point to a dedicated macro or environment).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\newcommand\fakematerial[1]{
    Material #1 - START

    \vspace{7cm}
    
    Material #1 - END 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \fakematerial{1}%
\end{minipage}
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \fakematerial{2}
\end{minipage}%

\medskip

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \fakematerial{3}%
\end{minipage}
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \fakematerial{4}
\end{minipage}%

\medskip

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \fakematerial{5}%
\end{minipage}
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \fakematerial{6}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```